# Python list initialization in for loop

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

How do initialize a list in a for loop:

```
for x, y in zip(list_x, list_y):
     x = f(x, y)
```

unfortunately, this loop does not alter list_x even though I want it to.

Is there a way to have references to the elements of list_x in the loop?

I realize I could use a list comprehension, but that's hard to read when **the for loop is very complicated**.

Edit: My `for` loop is 20 lines.  Would you normally put 20 lines into a single list comprehension?

Comment: If the desired result is only the modified list, you can move most of the complexity into `f` and use a comprehension. Otherwise, the explicit loop is much better.

Comment: Are there twenty lines having side effects? (If so, forget about list comprehensions!) And why aren't they part of `f`?

Comment: @delnan: what exactly do you mean by side effects?

Comment: @SilentGhost: Assignment statements have side effects.  Variables are changed.  A hard thing to do in a list comprehension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this do it?

```
# Create a temporary list to hold new x values
result = []

for x, y in zip(list_x, list_y):
     # Populate the new list
     result.append(f(x, y))

# Name your new list same as the old one
list_x = result
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, that works.  If that turns out to be the most pythonic way, I'll accept it in a day.

Comment: This is just a poor man's verbose list comprehension. Yes, that's what @Neil asked for, but that doesn't make it any better.

Comment: Agreed. Not necessarily less Pythonic IMHO, but usually less preferable for the trivial case above.

Answer (score 10):

why would list-comprehension be complicated?

```
list_x[:] = [f(tup) for tup in zip(list_x, list_y)]
```

Instead of having 20-line for loop, you could use a set of generator expressions or abstract a subset of code into an `f` function.

<sub>It's really is pointless to talk about what *could* be done w/o seeing the code.</sub>

Comment: +1 Agreed. I can understand reservations against nested loops with complex expressions, but this loop ain't nothing. (Minor Fix: Either `f(*tup)` or `f(x, y) for x, y in ...`)

Comment: Yes, the complexity could be factored out to `f` and you can even skip `tup` s based on some condition.

Comment: I honestly don't know: Is the `[:]` necessary?

Comment: It's what modifies `list_x`: you're setting the result of the comprehension into that slice (which happens to be the whole list).

Comment: @Neil: depends on whether you care about memory consumption and/or need original `list_x` variable.

Comment: Less about memory consumption and more about semantics: The `[:]` will make it modify the list in-place, i.e. visibly for everyone else who has a reference to the list. Constrast with just overwriting the local variable with a (reference to a) new list - everybody else keeps their reference to the unmodified list.

Answer (score 3):

This is just a poor man's verbose list comprehension, also.

```
def new_list( list_x, list_y ):
    for x, y in zip(list_x, list_y):
        yield f(x, y)

list_x = list( new_list( list_x, list_y ) )
```

Comment: I suppose one could say that `new_list` is a verbose generator expression. And `list(genexpr)` is indeed equivalent to (but in some versions slower than) list comprehension.

Comment: @S.Lott: `new_list` is a bad choice of name ... just re-read your last line of code: `list(new_list(....))`

Comment: @John Machin: True but unhelpful.  Is there anything in the question that would suggest a better name?  Do you have a better name?

Comment: @S.Lott: When name doesn't match functionality, always consider the alternative possibility that the name is OK but the functionality is wrong. In this case the question indicates that if in fact the OP actually wants a function that does everything, he'd be more interested in a new list than a generator.

Comment: @John Machin: True but still unhelpful.  What's the better name?

Comment: @S.Lott: I'm sorry, I didn't think you'd need such help. Using the OP's nomenclature: he wants to replace the contents of his `x` list or maybe he wants a whole new list, which he will refer to as `x`. Given that, possible descriptive names for your function are `replacement_x_iterable` and permutations thereof.